# Iphone:how to open proxy from iphone code to access a webservice

Tags: iphone, proxy

I am working on Iphone Application.One of my colleague has written a web service 
in Dot Net which i need to call from my Iphone end.

The web service is behind the proxy.I have to open the proxy before accessing
the webservice from Iphone end written in DOT NET.

As per the requirements
i have to pass the following parameters from Iphone to open the proxy so that i can access the webservice:
1) IP Address
2) Port
3)username
4)password
5)server location

I have no idea how to implement this.I am doing this for the first time.Have any one implemented this?I will really appreciate if any one can guide me how can i achieve this?

Thanks,
Shradha harne

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**ASIHttpRequest**](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use). This is an awesome library built on top of `NSURLConnection`.

The link I gave has a section "Working with Proxies". Check it out. Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks a lot Shrikar.Your answer really helped me.I appreciate your help so much .Thanks dear

Comment: Cool! Glad that my answer helped. If any answer has helped you, please mark it as correct answer (the green tick mark). This helps the community & anyone else looking for similar answer...